# Problema con espacios en Android

Tags: java, android, mysql

Tengo un formulario en **android** el cual se comunica con un `WebService` para llenar una base de datos de **MySql**, el problema es que cuando ejecuto la app y escribo en el `editText` por ejemplo el nombre, si escribo dos palabras los datos no llegan a MySQL, pero si lleno los `editText` solo con una palabra sin dejar espacios entonces si llegan a MySql

Este es mi codigo en Java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class FormNegocio extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText nombren, telefonon, direccionnR, direccionnE, correon, observacionesn;
    RadioButton tespecial, carga, encomiendan;
    Button confirmarnform, regresarnform;
    ListView listaResultado;
    String tipon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form_negocio);

        nombren = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nombren);
        telefonon = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.telefonon);
        direccionnR = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.direccionnR);
        direccionnE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.direccionnE);
        correon = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.correon);
        observacionesn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.observacionesn);

        tespecial = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.tespecial);
        carga = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.carga);
        encomiendan = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.encomiendan);

        confirmarnform = (Button)findViewById(R.id.confirmarNform);
        regresarnform = (Button)findViewById(R.id.regresarNform);

        confirmarnform.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (tespecial.isChecked()){
                    tipon = "T. Especial";
                }else if (carga.isChecked()){
                    tipon = "carga";
                }else if (encomiendan.isChecked()){
                    tipon = "encomienda";
                }

               final String nombreform = nombren.getText().toString().trim();

                String registro = "http://miurl.com/micarpeta/registrarn.php?idusuarion=NULL&nombren="+nombreform+"&telefonon="+telefonon.getText()+"&direccionnR="+direccionnR.getText()+"&direccionnE="+direccionnE.getText()+"&correon="+correon.getText()+"&tipon="+tipon+"&observacionesn="+observacionesn.getText();

                EnviarRecibirDatos(registro);
                Intent confirmarnform = new Intent(FormNegocio.this, Fin.class);
                startActivity(confirmarnform);
            }
        });


        regresarnform.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent regresarnform = new Intent(FormNegocio.this, Inicio.class);
                startActivity(regresarnform);
            }
        });
    }

    public void EnviarRecibirDatos(String URL){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tenemos tu solicitud", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                if (response.length()>0){
                    try {
                        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(response);
                        Log.i("sizejson",""+ja.length());

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }



}
```

Comment: El problema podria estar en la capa de android, de php o de mysql.
Descartaste, por debug o con un `Log.i` o alguna manera si en la linea final `String nombreform = ... `recibe correctamente el valor? Luego si en codigo php lo recepciona correctamente antes de enviarlo a MySql

Comment: Te sugiero que añadas tu codigo PHP

Comment: El problema podría estar en tu código de php o en la columna de tu tabla. Checa si te esta llegando bien el valor a tu api de php y si si, checa los logs de mysql, posiblemente sea por el tipo de campo que tengas en tu columna.

Comment: Te sugeriria que para trabajar con una WebService o cualquier API web uses es esquema REST usando peticiónes `GET` para traer datos, `POST` para insertar, `PUT` para actualizar datos, `DELETE` para borrar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso me ocurría a mi, te explico:

El problema viene cuando pasas los parámetros por GET al PHP, si pasas por ejemplo:

```
mipagina.com/script.php?nombre=pepe
```

Te lo acepta, pero...

```
mipagina.com/script.php?nombre=pepe garcía
```

No te lo acepta al tener ese espacio, la solución que yo le dí fue formatear dichos espacios en android antes de encapsularlos para mandarlos.

Reemplacé todos los " ", por "%20", el %20 reemplaza a los espacios en una cadena de texto de una URL, desde ese momento me empezó la app a guardarme las cadenas de textos con espacios en el mysql. Quedando la URL que envíes así:

```
mipagina.com/script.php?nombre=pepe%20garcía
```

Crea una función a la que la pasas una cadena de texto, y te haga un return con los espacios reemplazados.

Answer (score 3):

El problema lo estás teniendo al formar la url con el siguiente código:

```
String registro = "http://miurl.com/micarpeta/registrarn.php?idusuarion=NULL&nombren="+nombreform+"&telefonon="+telefonon.getText()+"&direccionnR="+direccionnR.getText()+"&direccionnE="+direccionnE.getText()+"&correon="+correon.getText()+"&tipon="+tipon+"&observacionesn="+observacionesn.getText();
```

ya que las url no permiten contener espacios en blanco, por lo que puedes echar un vistazo a la [documentación](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) de URLEncoder, quedando tu código de la siguiente forma:

```
String nombre = URLEncoder.encode(nombreform, "UTF-8");
String telefono = URLEncoder.encode(telefonon.getText(), "UTF-8");
String direccionR = URLEncoder.encode(direccionnR.getText(), "UTF-8");
String direccionE = URLEncoder.encode(direccionnE.getText(), "UTF-8");
String correo = URLEncoder.encode(correon.getText(), "UTF-8");
String tipo = URLEncoder.encode(tipon, "UTF-8");
String observaciones = URLEncoder.encode(observacionesn.getText(), "UTF-8");

String registro = "http://miurl.com/micarpeta/registrarn.php?idusuarion=NULL&nombren="+nombre+"&telefonon="+telefono+"&direccionnR="+direccionR+"&direccionnE="+direccionE+"&correon="+correo+"&tipon="+tipo+"&observacionesn="+observaciones;
```

**Nota**: Sólo necesitas codificar el valor de cada parámetro no la url entera.

**Nota 2**: Ten en cuenta que los espacios en los parámetros de consulta están representados por '+', no por '%20'. El '%20' suele usarse para representar espacios en URI (la parte antes del carácter de separador de cadena de la consulta URI '?'), No en la cadena de consulta (la parte después del '?').

Comment: Me parece que esto es lo que sucede, hay que codificar los valores como mencionas.

Comment: Si, es un error bastante común cuando se trabaja con URL